# Specflow running with MSTest

Tags: mstest, specflow

I am using VS2013.
I am trying to run the *.dll from the MSTest, but it fails without any execution.
If I execute the same test case manually, it always pass.

Below is the command line execution lines:

---

c:>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest" /testcontainer:"E:\E_Drive\TFS_Work\PlatformSoftware\Embedded\AutomatedRe
gressionTests\Main\bin\Debug\YDOA.dll" /category:"TRLYS1D"

Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 12.0.21005.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading E:\E_Drive\TFS_Work\PlatformSoftware\Embedded\AutomatedRegressionTests\Main\bin\Debug\YDOA.dll...
Starting execution...

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
Failed                YDOA.InputOutputFeature.RelayAndRelayFdbkAsUsedNormalAndFALSEAndTRUE_01
Failed                YDOA.InputOutputFeature.RelayAsUnusedNormalAndALLRelaysTRUE

0/2 test(s) Passed, 2 Failed

### Summary

Test Run Failed.
  Failed  2

---

Total   2
Results file:  c:\TestResults\Admin_GE-6QSVBDRLU204 2015-07-08 16_10_38.trx
Test Settings: Default Test Settings

---

I have the reference "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework" in my project.

mentioned is my AppConfig.

`<specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest"/>
    <stepAssemblies>`

In the SpecFlow - "Test Runner Tool", I have tried with all the options like : AUTO, ReSharper, VS2010MStest, VS2012, SpecRun....still I have the same problem.

I could not able to understand the problem.

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: Here is the execution command lines:

Comment: Are you running VS as Administrator?